# Why I receive "Carrier does not exist" if I specify carrier account in request?

Tags: shippo

I am trying to create [shippo batch labels](https://goshippo.com/docs/batch/) using java API. I have specified carrier objectID at `BatchShipment` level and at `Batch` level. When I check status of batch - it is `Invalid`, batch shipment status is also `Invalid` and there is message in batch shipment object: "*Carrier account with the provided object_id does not exist*". Do you have ideas why I am receiving this error?

Carrier object id was received by requesting all CarrierAccounts, here is kotlin snippet:

```
    Shippo.apiKey = ShippoSnippet.SHIPPO_API_KEY
    val all = CarrierAccount.all()
    print(all.data.firstOrNull{it.carrier.toLowerCase().contains("usps")}!!.objectId)
    //output is 50c0caf41f9b450ebe62f24daf2615be
```

Here is snippet how I specify carrier account at shipment level:
`BatchShipment.createForShipment(shipment, "50c0caf41f9b450ebe62f24daf2615be", "usps_first")`.

Batch was created:

```
val submitted = Batch.create("50c0caf41f9b450ebe62f24daf2615be", "usps_first", LabelFileType.PDF, null, batchShipments.toTypedArray())
val shippoId = submitted.id
```

Then I request batch object again with this snippet:

```
Batch.get(shippoId, 0, null)
```

But result is invalid and I am not sure why because I specify carrier `objectId`, as it written in [API docs](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#batches-batch-shipments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shippo support confirmed they have this issue with test key at current moment. It worked for me with live key.